# How can I filter a result in akka?

Tags: scala, filter, akka

I have a Future containing this List of Int: `List(40, 42, 41)`. I tried to filter it using the filter-function as I use normally: `f.filter(_ == 42)`.
f is the future containing the List. I got it from another Actor. On execution I get this MatchError:

```
[ERROR] [12/03/2012 09:37:34.252] [playground-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-1] [akka://playground/user/sender] List(40, 42, 41) (of class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)
scala.MatchError: List(40, 42, 41) (of class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)
```

I don't understand that error and am not able to fix it. Can anyone help me please?

**Edit**

Here is the code in one piece:

```
case class Send(target: ActorRef, msg: String)

class SendingActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(1 second)

  def receive = {
    case Send(target, msg) =>
      log.info("will send %s".format(msg))
      val f = target ? msg
      log.info("awaited " + Await.result(f.filter(_ == 42), timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[List[Int]])
  }

}
```

Comment: Could you show the relevant code as a whole please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to filter the list of ints by calling filter on the future of the list of ints. You need to "unpack" the list first.

```
Await.result(f map { list => list filter { _ == 42 } })
```

Comment: Thank you this works. After some tries, I figured out, that I needed the explicit type for this.